# How to send raw json data to put method in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, api, rest

i am try send raw data into PUT method , but i am getting error as "The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway"
But same data i try to use in Postman Agent, its working.

What i tried

```
   Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    req.ContentType = contentType
    req.Method = method
    req.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
    req.Headers.Add("x-api-key:xxxxxY0tZN55jbXnY05Oxxxxx")

    Dim stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
    stream.Close()

    Dim response = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response)
    Dim res = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return res
End Function
```

Calling function

```
    Dim postdata As String = "[{barcod:A0000041},{barcode:A0000113}]"
    Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
  
    Dim Uri As New Uri("https://sample.com/xxxxx/xxxxx?funcName=UpdateBaarcode")

    Dim result_post = SendRequest(Uri, data, "text/plain", "PUT")
```

What i missing , pls reply.

Regards,
Aravind

Comment: You might want to look at moving to HttpClient rather than WebRequest which I believe is almost outdated/obsolete now.

Answer (score 0):

For REST API

I use WebRequest using DirectCast.

It's been so long I can't remember why. TT

Try like the code below.

```
Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest= DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)

    req.ContentType = contentType
    req.Method = method
    req.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
    req.Headers.Add("x-api-key:xxxxxY0tZN55jbXnY05Oxxxxx")

    Dim stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
    stream.Close()

    Dim response = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim res = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return res
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i am getting this error in screenshot  - http://prntscr.com/1s1j4zl
but same data with put method in postman agent working fine.